# Deny access to route outside of kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I'm working with a large monolithic application with some private routes. These private routes are currently managed by an plain classic nginx  server.

I need to migrate this to Kubernetes, and I must deny all external access to these routes. I'm using GKE, and AFAIK, privatize routes can be done inside the nginx-ingress controller.

I'm trying with server-snippet, but it doesn't seems to work.
Here's the current code:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.org/websocket-services: service-ws
    nginx.org/server-snippet: |
      location /private {
        allow 10.100.0.0/16; #Pods IPs
        allow 10.200.0.0/16; #Pods IPs
        deny all; 
      }
  generation: 3
```

The result is that /private routes always return 200 instead of 401/403.
I've also tried to create a redirection instead of allow/deny, and also get 200 instead of 301 redirections.

Do you have some ideas or tips to make this work?

Comment: Maybe a simple way would be to disallow or avoid having an Ingress path for these routes , also have you considered white-listing your private ips

Comment: Thank you! The trick was that the prefix is not up-to-date as I mention in my answer i've just written.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following many links, the trick was the prefix is not up-to-date in most documentation:

Here's a working sample:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
            location /management_api {
                allow 1.2.3.4/16;  # Pod address range
                allow 1.3.4.5/16;   # Pod address range
                deny all;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_intercept_errors on;
                proxy_set_header Connection "";
                proxy_set_header X-CF-Visitor $http_cf_visitor;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://10.11.12.13;
            }
```

Enjoy!